# Why is the plane x=2/5 crossing the y-axis instead of the x-axis?

Tags: 3d

Why is the plane x=2/5 crossing the y-axis instead of the x-axis? I thought it would be opposite like when you graph a line. Would the vector be (.4,0,0)[image]

Comment: But it **crosses** the $x$-axis, at $\left(\frac25,0,0\right)$ as it should. That axis is the red one.

Comment: On geogebra, it is telling me that the x-axis is the green one and the y-axis is the red one. That is why I am sooo confused.

Comment: If x=2/5 then any point (2/5,s,t) is on the plane. it will never intersect the y- or z-axes, just like in 2d, the line x=2/5 never crosses the y-axis

Comment: **Who** is telling you that the $x$-axis is the red one? Create the point $(1,0,0)$ and you will see that it lies on the red axis, not on the green one.

Comment: [This page](https://help.geogebra.org/topic/i-have-changed-the-colors-of-the-axes-to-black) says "...the axes in their default colors of Red, Green, and Blue."

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I thought I was going crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with your software, but geometrically the plane $x=2/5$ should cross the $x$ axis, and *only* the $x$ axis, at the point $(2/5,0,0)$. The values of $y$ and $z$ can be anything, but the plane never crosses either the $y$ or $z$ axes, because that would require $x=0$.

Comment: Thank you! GeoGebra confused me